# Applying for visa outside country of origin

Tags: visas, usa, canada, brazil, colombian-citizens

I am a Colombian citizen with a Colombian passport and a US tourist visa. 
I will be in the USA for a couple weeks and then travel straight from there to Brasil, and then straight from Brasil to Canada.
Can i apply for a Canadian tourist visa from the US? 
And if I were to need any additional permits to enter Brasil, could I get them from the US too? 
Would any Brasil and Canada embassies in the US be able to help me with that?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: In general: check the embassy website for visa. They will write who is allowed to apply (and possibly you must call, and possibly you will not get the correct answer: it is a mess if you try to do non standard procedures). Country of origin is usually not important, but country of residence it is.

Comment: @Sam You may only need an ESTA for Canada, depending on your circumstances eg whether you have a valid US visa http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/visit/visas.asp

Comment: Echoing the comment above, you'd want to check the site/call the embassy to confirm. A number of embassies will request you apply from your country of residence.

Comment: Check with the Canadian embassy in US as it depends on whether or not they approve of it. In general, applying for visas outside your country of origin/citizenship/long-term residency is risky based on anecdotal evidence. If you still have some time before your trip I'd suggest apply for Canadian visa in Colombia itself.

Answer (score 2):

A citizen of Colombia does not need a visa to enter Brazil for a visit of up to 90 days. You can just show up and present your passport or Cédula de Ciudadanía (ID card).

You do need a visa to visit Canada though. You are allowed to apply for it from within the United States, but since it may take [several weeks](https://www.canada.ca/en/immigration-refugees-citizenship/services/application/check-processing-times.html) to process, you probably do not have enough time to receive it. If possible you should apply for the Canada visa before you leave Colombia. At the time of writing, the processing time for applications made in the USA is 42 days, and from Colombia is 16 days.

If you apply from the USA, there are [special instructions](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/pdf/kits/forms/IMM5876E.pdf) to be aware of in addition to the [normal applicaton process](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/information/applications/visa.asp?countrySelect=US). Otherwise follow the [application process in Colombia](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/information/applications/visa.asp?countrySelect=CO).